# Unable to change the value of a @State variable in swift?

Tags: swift, variables, swiftui, state

Swift 5.x iOS 15

Just playing around with an idea and hit a roadblock? Why can I not change the value of this state variable in this code?

```
struct ContentView: View {
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.25, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

@State var rexShape = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 128, height: 128)

var body: some View {
    Arc(startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(180), clockwise: true)
        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
        .frame(width: 128, height: 128, alignment: .center)
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            rexShape.height -= 10
        }
        
}
}

struct Arc: Shape {

  var startAngle: Angle
  var endAngle: Angle
  var clockwise: Bool

  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rect.width / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: clockwise)

    return path
  }
}
```

The line rexShape.height is telling me height is a get-only property? which makes no sense to me cause rexShape should be a variable? Am I simply losing my mind...

Comment: its not a huge deal since your timer frequency is so fast but it should be @State to prevent the timer being restarted every time ContentView is init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay close attention to the error message, the compiler isn't complaining about `rexShape` not being mutable, but about `CGRect.height` not being mutable.

To change the only `height` or `weight` of a `CGRect`, you need to do it via its `size` property.

```
rexShape.size.height -= 10
```